# Create a column in a dataframe depending on values in another with if statement

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

What I'm trying to do is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Person":["John", "Myla", "Mary", "John", "Myla"],
               "Age1": [24, 6, 21, 33, 17],
               "Single": [False, True, True, True, False]})

   Age1 Person Single
 0  24 John False 
 1   6 Myla True 
 2  21 Mary True 
 3  33 John True 
 4  17 Myla False
```

From the above dataframe, I need to add a new column that will show "1" if the the age if the person is above the age of another dataframe.

My second dataframe is this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Person":["John", "Myla", "Mary"],
               "Age1": [25, 10, 15] }).set_index(['Person'])

         Age1
 Person 
  John   25
  Myla   10 
  Mary   15
```

The results ideally would be:

```
   Age1 Person Single Final
 0 24 John False       0
 1  6 Myla True        0
 2 21 Mary True        1
 3 33 John True        1
 4 17 Myla False       1
```

So, all John's in my first table with an age greater that 25 in the second table will be given a 1, otherwise 2.

I tried doing it with a dictionary,

```
a=df2.set_index('Person').T.to_dict('list')
```

but my dictionary looks like this:

```
{'John': [24L], 'Mary': [15L], 'Myla': [0L]}
```

but it's getting me really confused. I also thought about merging the 2 dataframes and then comparing to create the new column, but is there any other more straight option?

Or if I manage to convert the 2nd ddataframe in a dictionary, I could use map
df['Final'] = df.Person.map(dictionary) but still shouldn't compare the ages. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), compare by [`lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.lt.html) (`<`) and last cast boolean mask to integer:

```
df['Final'] = df['Person'].map(df2['Age1']).lt(df['Age1']).astype(int)
print (df)
  Person  Age1  Single  Final
0   John    24   False      0
1   Myla     6    True      0
2   Mary    21    True      1
3   John    33    True      1
4   Myla    17   False      1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['Person'].map(df2['Age1']))
0    25
1    10
2    15
3    25
4    10
Name: Person, dtype: int64
```